# Indexing unknown nodes in Firebase

Tags: indexing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data structure is like this:

```
firebase-endpoint/updates/<location_id>/<update_id>
```

each location has many updates that firebase adds as "array" elements.

How can I index on the "validFrom" property of each update if the location_id is unknown before insertion into the databse?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "updates": {
      "<location_id>": { // WHAT IS THIS NODE SUPPOSED TO BE?
        ".indexOn": ["validFrom"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

data structure sample

```
{
    "71a57e17cbfd0f524680221b9896d88c5ab400b3": {
        "-KBHwULMDZ4EL_B48-if": {
            "place_id": "71a57e17cbfd0f524680221b9896d88c5ab400b3",
            "name": "Gymbox Bank",
            "statusValueId": 2,
            "update_id": "NOT_SET",
            "user_id": "7017a0f5-04a7-498c-9ccd-c547728deffb",
            "validFrom": 1456311760554,
            "votes": 1
        }
    },
    "d9a02ab407543155d86b84901c69797cb534ac17": {
        "-KBHgPkz_buv7DzOFHbD": {
            "place_id": "d9a02ab407543155d86b84901c69797cb534ac17",
            "name": "The Ivy Chelsea Garden",
            "update_id": "NOT_SET",
            "user_id": "7017a0f5-04a7-498c-9ccd-c547728deffb",
            "validFrom": 1456307547374,
            "votes": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Update: I don't think this is a dupe of the said question becauase that question doesn't have a parent object with an unknown id as well. ie both `<location_id>` and `<update_id>` are free form keys and cannot be set by hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a bit more digging in the docs and I think this should work:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "updates": {
      "$location_id": { // $location_id should act like a wild card
        ".indexOn": ["validFrom"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Almost. You need to put `.indexOn` one level higher, so as a child of `updates`.

Comment: but the field validFrom is a property of an update, not a location? ie it is doubly nested on unkown ids

Comment: Yes. But the query runs on the `updates` location, so that's where you're creating the index.

Comment: How will it know that "validFrom" is a property of the most deeply nested child?

Comment: Ah, I missed that part, sorry about that. Indeed, since you're nesting you need to put the index where you've put it in this answer. But how are you going to query this structure?

Comment: Perhaps you can make `location_id` a property of each update (a sibling of `validFrom`. Then the `.indexOn` should be below `updates`.