# How to index firebase data with firestore query based on dynamic key?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to add a query where I have two `array-contains`, which turned out not going to work as Firebase doesn't support it.

```
const initialQuery = Firebase.firestore.collection('class')
    .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    .where('access.readAccess.classrooms', 'array-contains', id)
    .where('keywords', 'array-contains', keyword)
    .limit(5);
```

So I ended up writing something like below.

```
const initialQuery = firebase.firestore().collection('class')
    .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    .where(`accessibleUsers.${id}.hasAccessTo.classrooms.read`, '==', true)
    .where('keywords', 'array-contains', keyword)
    .limit(5);
```

Now the issue goes while trying to index this data I see the index is happing only for a particular id. And after seeing a few answers in StackOverflow I am bit confused with the whole indexing.

Based on this, [Indexing unknown nodes in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598996/indexing-unknown-nodes-in-firebase)
it is saying remove the `` .where(`accessibleUsers.${id}.hasAccessTo.class.read`, '==', true) `` and add a rule to firebase security rules to read only where he has access to?

How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question you linked is about the Firebase Realtime Database, where indexes are defined inside the security rules for the database. You're using Cloud Firestore (a completely different database), where indexes are defined in the Firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

With this code:

```
.where(`accessibleUsers.${id}.hasAccessTo.classrooms.read`, '==', true)
```

You can indeed query whether the user had read access to multiple class rooms. But the cost for that is that you'll need to define an index for each value of `id`.

Fair warning: while this is technically possible, it is often not feasible to maintain these indexes manually. You may want to consider storing a data structure that makes it more feasible, for example by also storing the classes for each user.

Comment: Umm, I see what you saying. So for each accessible user, I have to index them? is there a automated way to do that?
2nd option, yes I can put each class document to the user, but a class document is accessible to many users and a user can have many class documents access. Is there no better way to do this?
My endgoal is to have acess to a document where the user has read access and matches a keyword he/she is looking for.

Comment: Automated way: well, you'll write the code for it, and after that it happens automatically. There's no non-code option for generating these reverse indexes.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, so the last question, this is what I did to kinda make it work. `allow list: if request.auth.token.id in resource.data.access.readAccess. classrooms;` and `allow read: if request.auth.token.id in resource.data.access.readAccess. classrooms;` added these two rules for my initial load of the list. Later on when user query on `.where('keywords', 'array-contains', keyword)` I am going to let firebase complain about `Missing or insufficient permissions`, will be this an issue?